# SQL Server Query retrieves incorrect value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is transaction item table.

[image: item]

Now I wanted to retrieve total amount of the transaction, total amount with discount, total discount and Sales Tax for which I wrote the below query:

```
select t1.av_transaction_id,
    round(SUM((t1.gross_line_amount - t1.pos_discount_amount)), 2) AS total_amount_with_discount,
    round(SUM((t1.gross_line_amount)), 2) AS total_amount,
    round(SUM((t1.pos_discount_amount)), 2)    AS total_discount,
    round(SUM((t2.gross_line_amount)), 2)    AS total_sales_tax
from transaction_detail as t1 
inner join transaction_detail as t2 on     t1.av_transaction_id=t2.av_transaction_id
    and t1.transaction_date=t2.transaction_date
where (t1.sku_id is not null or t1.line_action_display_descr='sold')
    and t2.line_object_description='S6 Sales Tax'
    and t1.av_transaction_id='581280193'
group by t1.av_transaction_id
```

But I get the following output:

```
av_transaction_id:581280193 || total_amount_with_discount:5.01 || total_amount:6.67 || total_discount:1.66 || total_Sales_tax:0.66
```

As you may see in the screenshot the Sales Tax should be 0.22 but somehow the query returns 0.66.

Can someone pleas help me in optimizing this query and let me know why does it return an incorrect value ?

Comment: Well, I need to run this query for multiple transactions. To make it simple I posted it with just one transaction id

Comment: Well, there are three records for this transaction where the sku_id is not null or the  display description is 'sold'. All three of those will match with the Sales Tax record for the join... and then you take the SUM(). So .22 + .22 + .22 = .66

Comment: Why are you doing a join here? This is a self join on the same data. Something seems amiss here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That makes sense, you have any idea then how to retrieve Sales Tax? I need to run this query for multiple transactions.

Comment: Good question asked clearly with clear expected results and description of problem. Up voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three records for this transaction where the sku_id is not null or the display description is 'sold'. All three of those will match with the Sales Tax record for the join... and then you take the SUM(). So .22 + .22 + .22 = .66

To fix this, I'd use conditional aggregation rather than a self-join:

```
select t1.av_transaction_id,
    round(SUM(CASE WHEN t1.sku_id is not null or t1.line_action_display_descr='sold' THEN t1.gross_line_amount - t1.pos_discount_amount ELSE 0 END)), 2) AS total_amount_with_discount,
    round(SUM(CASE WHEN t1.sku_id is not null or t1.line_action_display_descr='sold' THEN t1.gross_line_amount ELSE 0 END), 2) AS total_amount,
    round(SUM(CASE WHEN t1.sku_id is not null or t1.line_action_display_descr='sold' THEN t1.pos_discount_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)    AS total_discount,
    round(SUM(CASE WHEN t1.line_object_description='S6 Sales Tax' THEN t1.gross_line_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)    AS total_sales_tax
from transaction_detail as t1 
where  t1.av_transaction_id='581280193'
group by t1.av_transaction_id
```

Though this repeats the same condition, so you might be able to wrap that up further to only resolve the condition once.

Comment: This works but somehow the results are multiplied by 10, so instead of .22, I get 2.2. But Thanks.

Comment: @user9230890 There are 10 rows for the transaction. Did you completely remove the join, as in this example, or is it still joining to itself?

Comment: Before editing your response, t2 was mentioned in your answer hence I kept the join  but after removing it your solution seemed to work. Thank You. In the meantime I also posted my solution.

Comment: @user9230890 I like this answer because it doesn't do a self join. Up voted. See my answer in the spirit of correcting the problem with the original query from OP by making minimum changes to original query.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks to previous respondents:

```
select t1.av_transaction_id,
round(SUM((t1.gross_line_amount - t1.pos_discount_amount)), 2)    AS    total_amount_with_discount,
round(SUM((t1.gross_line_amount)), 2)    AS total_amount,
round(SUM((t1.pos_discount_amount)), 2) AS total_discount,
round(SUM((t2.gross_line_amount))/count(t1.gross_line_amount), 2) AS total_sales_tax
  from transaction_detail as t1 inner join
    transaction_detail as t2 on t1.av_transaction_id=t2.av_transaction_id
and t1.transaction_date=t2.transaction_date
where (t1.sku_id is not null or t1.line_action_display_descr='sold')
and t2.line_object_description='S6 Sales Tax'
and t1.av_transaction_id='581280193'
group by t1.av_transaction_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need to do is to not sum the sales tax, so your query would look like this:

```
select t1.av_transaction_id,
    round(SUM((t1.gross_line_amount - t1.pos_discount_amount)), 2) AS total_amount_with_discount,
    round(SUM((t1.gross_line_amount)), 2) AS total_amount,
    round(SUM((t1.pos_discount_amount)), 2)    AS total_discount,
    round(t2.gross_line_amount, 2)    AS total_sales_tax
from transaction_detail as t1 
inner join transaction_detail as t2 on     t1.av_transaction_id=t2.av_transaction_id
    and t1.transaction_date=t2.transaction_date
where (t1.sku_id is not null or t1.line_action_display_descr='sold')
    and t2.line_object_description='S6 Sales Tax'
    and t1.av_transaction_id='581280193'
group by t1.av_transaction_id
```

I mocked up your table with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE SO_TEST
(
    intTransID INT
    , objDesc VARCHAR(MAX)
    , displayDesc VARCHAR(MAX)
    , lintAmt FLOAT
    , discAmount FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO SO_TEST (intTransID, objDesc, displayDesc, lintAmt, discAmount)
VALUES
(1,'emp merch','sold',2.29,.57)
, (1,'emp merch','sold',1.89,.47)
, (1,'emp merch tax','sold',2.49,.62)
, (1,'sales tax','charged',.22,0.0)
, (1,'blah','blah',1.0,2.0)
, (2,'emp merch','sold',3.29,1.57)
, (2,'emp merch','sold',2.89,1.47)
, (2,'emp merch tax','sold',3.49,1.62)
, (2,'sales tax','charged',1.22,0.0)
, (2,'blah','blah',1.0,2.0)
```

And came up with this query that displays what I believe you want to have it display:

```
SELECT t1.intTransID
, ROUND(SUM(t1.lintAmt - t1.discAmount),2) tot_amt_disc
, ROUND(SUM(t1.lintAmt), 2) tot_amt
, ROUND(SUM(t1.discAmount),2) disc_amt
, ROUND(t2.lintAmt,2) sales_tax
FROM SO_TEST t1
JOIN SO_TEST t2 ON 1=1
    AND t1.intTransID = t2.intTransID
WHERE t1.displayDesc IN ('sold','charged')
    AND t1.objDesc <> 'sales tax'
    AND t2.objDesc = 'sales tax'
GROUP BY t1.intTransID, t2.lintAmt
```

The results of the query are as follows:

[image]

This works for multiple transactions as asked.